# ASP.net how to make RedirectToRouteResult() to a url configured in MapRoute()

Tags: asp.net, redirect, routes

I set a route map in RouteConfig.cs like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "prefix/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MainView", action = "Index" }
        );
```

And I want to do a redirect in MainView/Index under some situation, so I write code like below, and return it:

```
        RedirectToRouteResult redirect = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Home", controller = "Account"}));
```

I wish it would return the url like: localhost/prefix/Account/Home, but the result is localhost/Account/Home. How can I make the redirect result to be localhost/prefix/Account/Home?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the mvc library and have tried doing a Return RedirectToAction("Home", "Account");  ?

Comment: Yes, I use the mvc5 and I also tried the RedirectToAction("Home", "Account"), it still return the unexpected url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I made a stupid fault, there is [Authorize] attribute on this action, so the return url is made by this attribute. I correct this code and get the expected url.